# DOSBox-X shows empty rectangles instead standard characters

Tags: 22.04, software-center, dosbox

I use Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS.

I installed DOSBox-X from the Software Center (Snap).

I just get this screen...

[image]

What's wrong here?

How can I fix this?

BTW: I can perfectly run the DOSBox (without "-X") app.

Comment: It's just some wierd glitch. try using a different font.

Comment: or you can use DOSBox instead.([install guide](https://pimylifeup.com/ubuntu-dosbox/))

Comment: The font that the window is trying to use is not installed, thus cannot be shown (*and the systems shows it as a box*). Either a config isn't ideal, it requires another font, or changing font uses fix. Sorry I rarely use `dosbox` & then only from terminal (ie. not the Xorg version).